# MQ Queue Response no esperado en Business Services

Tags: oracle-11g, websphere-mq

Que tal comunidad!

Estoy teniendo un problema con un response proveniente de una cola MQ.

Estoy enviando una trama que supuestamente es valida a un Business Service de OSB 11g.

Me tendria que devolver una trama con una estructura totalmente distinta pero me encuentro que al volver el mensaje me devuelve la misma trama con un "NK" incrustado, que es lo unico que cambia.

Alguien sabe interpretrar que es ese "NK" que me devuelve en el mensaje de response?

No estoy seguro si estoy enviando bien los headers tampoco.

Por favor si alguien sabe de algunos tutoriales de como enviar tramas a través de Business Services a colas MQ se lo agradeceria muchisimo.

Dejo la captura del response que me devuelve el BS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje que recibes es emitido por la aplicación **Servidora**, por tanto deberías hablar con el responsable de la aplicación destino para saber que significa ese **NK**.

Al llegar a leer el **Mensaje** de respuesta has podido escribir el **Mensaje-Pregunta**, por tanto tu cabecera **MQMD** es correcta desde la óptica del **MQ**, otra cosa es, si la aplicación destino lo admite como lo envías.